# Telegram bot api suddenly stops responding after sucessful exhaustive previous testing

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, tls1.2

I have an expected last-minute failure regarding the interaction of our code with a Telegram bot API. I have been using a Nordic Sem. gently provided Telegram related code running over its nRF9160 chip.

Everything has worked properly and continuously for several days, with the mentioned code managing both outcoming and incoming Telegram messages successfully and without interruption until last week, when the code suddenly become unable to deal with the Telegram API and started delivering the errno22 each time it executed the send function below stated.

```
int num_bytes = send(client_fd, send_buf, send_data_len, 0)
```

Error:

> ERROR!!! -> num_bytes = -1

As far as I know, this error means Invalid Argument, but I do obviously pass to the function the same arguments used from the beginning of the successful tests (nothing has been changed between successful and failed operation), so I cannot understand this unpredictable program break.

On the other hand, I have been aware that last week Telegram deprecated the use of TLS versions 1.0 and 1.1 and strongly recommended developers to upgrade to 1.2v to avoid service interruption. Theoretically, this update should not suppose a problem since the code provided by the chip support staff states within its arguments the TLS 1.2 version (see below) and, thus, I must assume that this is the version currently use by the chip manufacturer.

```
int client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TLS_1_2)
```

Nevertheless, information about this subject or any detected issues concerning the new TLS Telegram requirements would be very much appreciated as well as any other suggestion of how I can work around this issue.